# How to pass dependency files to sagemaker SKLearnProcessor and use it in Pipeline?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, scikit-learn, amazon-sagemaker

I need to import function from different python scripts, which will used inside `preprocessing.py` file. I was not able to find a way to pass the dependent files to `SKLearnProcessor` Object, due to which I am getting `ModuleNotFoundError`.

**Code:**

```
from sagemaker.sklearn.processing import SKLearnProcessor
from sagemaker.processing import ProcessingInput, ProcessingOutput

sklearn_processor = SKLearnProcessor(framework_version='0.20.0',
                                     role=role,
                                     instance_type='ml.m5.xlarge',
                                     instance_count=1)


sklearn_processor.run(code='preprocessing.py',
                      inputs=[ProcessingInput(
                        source=input_data,
                        destination='/opt/ml/processing/input')],
                      outputs=[ProcessingOutput(output_name='train_data',
                                                source='/opt/ml/processing/train'),
                               ProcessingOutput(output_name='test_data',
                                                source='/opt/ml/processing/test')],
                      arguments=['--train-test-split-ratio', '0.2']
                     )
```

I would like to pass,
`dependent_files = ['file1.py', 'file2.py', 'requirements.txt']`. So, that `preprocessing.py` have access to all the dependent modules.

And also need to install libraries from `requirements.txt` file.

Can you share any work around or a right way to do this?

**Update-25-11-2021:**

**Q1.**(Answered but looking to solve using `FrameworkProcessor`)

[Here](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/blob/99f023e76a5db060907a796d4d8fee550f005844/src/sagemaker/processing.py#L1426), the `get_run_args` function, is handling `dependencies`, `source_dir` and `code` parameters by using [FrameworkProcessor](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/blob/99f023e76a5db060907a796d4d8fee550f005844/src/sagemaker/processing.py#L1265). Is there any way that we can set this parameters from `ScriptProcessor` or `SKLearnProcessor` or any other `Processor` to set them?

**Q2.**

Can you also please show some reference to use our `Processor` as `sagemaker.workflow.steps.ProcessingStep` and then use in `sagemaker.workflow.pipeline.Pipeline`?

For having `Pipeline`, do we need `sagemaker-project` as mandatory or can we create `Pipeline` directly without any `Sagemaker-Project`?

Comment: have you tried to add extra `ProcessingInput` to download the source code?

Comment: @AbdelrahmanMaharek Yes, I tried that. For that we need to add source code to `s3` and pass that path to `ProcessingInput`. In this case, I'm not able to install dependent modules.

Comment: @AbdelrahmanMaharek Can you please check the updated question? Is there any direction you can provide to resolve this?

Comment: sorry, I've just seen this. I can see that you have managed to find a workaround by @tulio-casagrande

Comment: @AbdelrahmanMaharek Yes, using `ScriptProcessor` we can add custom `image_uri` which will be having libraries installed present in `requirements.txt`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There are a couple of options for you to accomplish that.

One that is really simple is adding all additional files to a folder, example:

```
.
├── my_package
│   ├── file1.py
│   ├── file2.py
│   └── requirements.txt
└── preprocessing.py
```

Then send this entire folder as another input under the same `/opt/ml/processing/input/code/`, example:

```py
from sagemaker.sklearn.processing import SKLearnProcessor
from sagemaker.processing import ProcessingInput, ProcessingOutput

sklearn_processor = SKLearnProcessor(
    framework_version="0.20.0",
    role=role,
    instance_type="ml.m5.xlarge",
    instance_count=1,
)

sklearn_processor.run(
    code="preprocessing.py",  # <- this gets uploaded as /opt/ml/processing/input/code/preprocessing.py
    inputs=[
        ProcessingInput(source=input_data, destination='/opt/ml/processing/input'),
        # Send my_package as /opt/ml/processing/input/code/my_package/
        ProcessingInput(source='my_package/', destination="/opt/ml/processing/input/code/my_package/")
    ],
    outputs=[
        ProcessingOutput(output_name="train_data", source="/opt/ml/processing/train"),
        ProcessingOutput(output_name="test_data", source="/opt/ml/processing/test"),
    ],
    arguments=["--train-test-split-ratio", "0.2"],
)
```

What happens is that `sagemaker-python-sdk` is going to put your argument `code="preprocessing.py"` under `/opt/ml/processing/input/code/` and you will have `my_package/` under the same directory.

**Edit:**

For the `requirements.txt`, you can add to your `preprocessing.py`:

```py
import sys
import subprocess

subprocess.check_call([
    sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", "-r",
    "/opt/ml/processing/input/code/my_package/requirements.txt",
])
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Can I assume that `input_data` as a folder in s3 bucket? I mean `input_data` contains multiple folders and data files that needed for `preprocessing.py` file and I will pass root folder will all the data as input i.e., `input_data`.

Comment: Can you also please show some reference to use `.run(...` as `sagemaker.workflow.steps.ProcessingStep` and then use in `sagemaker.workflow.pipeline.Pipeline`?

Comment: Exactly as you said, if your `input_data` is pointing to an s3 prefix (folder), such as `s3://my_bucket/data/`, all files from `data/` are sent to the job. 

[Here's a reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/define-pipeline.html) on how to use a `ProcessingStep` instead of manually calling `.run(...)`, most arguments are basically the same.

Comment: This is great. Is there a reference/documentation that states that the code goes to "/opt/ml/processing/input/code/"? Haven't been able to find it, only some vague hints in some examples.

Comment: hey @oW_, not really a documentation, but you can check [here](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/blob/7e2c7ab480b2b99ec6d580c1bf9e3be849c8db80/src/sagemaker/processing.py#L669-L692) in the SDK where the `code`  argument is handled.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't supported in SKLearnProcessor. You'd need to package your dependencies in docker image and create a custom `Processor` (e.g. a [ScriptProcessor](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/training/processing.html#sagemaker.processing.ScriptProcessor)  with the image_uri of the docker image you created.)

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/blob/99f023e76a5db060907a796d4d8fee550f005844/src/sagemaker/processing.py#L1426), the `get_run_args` function, is handling `dependencies`, `source_dir` and `code` parameters. Is there any way that we can set this parameters from `ScriptProcessor` or any other `Processor` to set them?